# Can you index on timestamp difference between tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have two tables, Users and Transactions. In both tables, rows have a timestamp.

I am running into performance issues when running complex queries where the transaction dates are being normalized to reflect at what point of a user experience they happened (i.e. how many days after a user joined was the transaction processed).

This "normalized day" measure is calculated as

```
ceil(extract(days from T.tdate - U.created_at)) +1
```

Is there any way to index this such that I can increase the speed of the query?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make such index directly.

You can add another field to the T table, which would store the value of your formula, and you can add an index on that field. You can maintain the value of that field using triggers.

Answer (score 2):

No: PostgreSQL doesn't [currently](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html) allow the creation of an index which references more than one table.

Alternatively you could:

- Follow maniek's suggestion of using triggers to compute timestamp differences on insert/updates to both of the tables.
- Use Postgresql 9.3's [CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) which allows you to define the view which takes a snapshot of the view's resultset and stores it as a table. Note that any changes made to the source tables after this snapshot are not automatically included. You can use [REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) to update this view, just before generating reports for an updated snapshot.